# ExpressJS authorization with JWT - Is this correct?

Tags: express, jwt

I have a small ExpressJS server with a login feature. Some pages are secured with self-written authenticate middleware that checks if your Json WebToken is correct.

I read that just one Json WebToken isn't secure enough and that you need a refresh token as well. So I added a Refresh Token. This is all verified on the server.

Now when the token is expired, I check if the user has a refreshToken and if so I create a new token and set it as a cookie. Like this:

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
// Simple array holding the issued refreshTokens
const { refreshTokens } = require('../lib/auth.js');

module.exports.authenticateToken = function(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.cookies.token;
  const refreshToken = req.cookies.refreshToken;

  if(token === null) return res.redirect('/login');

  try {
    const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
    if(verified) return next();
  } catch(err) {
    try {
      const refreshInDb = refreshTokens.find(token => token === refreshToken);
      const refreshVerified = refreshInDb && jwt.verify(refreshToken, process.env.REFRESHTOKEN_SECRET);
      const newToken = jwt.sign({ email: refreshVerified.email }, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: 20 });
      res.cookie('token', newToken, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
      return next();
    } catch(err) {
      return res.redirect('/login');
    }
  }
};
```

Now is this code correct & secure enough for a small webapplication? Am I missing stuff? It feels so... easy?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are veryfing both tokens at the same endpoint. This approach is wrong.

In your login endpoint, validate the user and password against database. If credentials are correct we respond with an access token and a refresh token

```js
router.post('/login',
  asyncWrap(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body
    await validateUser(username, password)

    return res.json({
      access_token: generateAccessToken(), // expires in 1 hour
      refresh_token: generateRefreshToken(), // expires in 1 month
    })
  })
)
```

In your authenticated routes, you should validate only the access token (the user should send ONLY this one)

```js
// middleware to validate the access token
export const validateToken = asyncWrap(async (req, res, next) => {
  const data = await verifyAccessToken(req.headers.authorization)
  req.auth = data
  next()
})
```

If the access token expires, the user should refresh its token. In this endpoint we will validate the refresh token and respond with two new tokens:

```js
router.post('/refresh',
  asyncWrap(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { refresh_token } = req.body
    await verifyRefreshToken(refresh_token)

    return res.json({
      access_token: generateAccessToken(), // expires in 1 hour
      refresh_token: generateRefreshToken(), // expires in 1 month
    })
  })
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the code examples! So on each request I should verify the JWT and if it expired I should redirect the user to the refresh route and back to the requested source again with a valid JWT?

Comment: Refreshing the client's token is responsability of the client. If the client receives a "token expired" error at some time, the own client should use the refresh endpoint to get a new valid access token. Once the token is refreshed, he should repeat the first request that failed. You can use libraries like `axios-auth-refresh` to create this logic easily.

Answer (score 1):

> I read that just one Json WebToken isn't secure enough and that you need a refresh token as well. So I added a Refresh Token. This is all verified on the server.

Using refresh tokens has nothing to do with security of the JWT or access token. Refresh tokens are just a UX feature. They allow you to get new access tokens without asking the user to authorize again. Having a refresh token in your app doesn't automatically make it more secure.

> Now when the token is expired, I check if the user has a refreshToken and if so I create a new token and set it as a cookie. Like this:

When implemented this way the refresh token doesn't grant any more security to your application. You could as well keep the access tokens in the db and refresh them when they are expired.

Are you sure that you need JWTs at all? It looks like you're using them as you would use a session based on cookies. It should be simpler to deal with sessions. You are using http-only cookies for your tokens so you already use it pretty much like a session.

> Now is this code correct & secure enough for a small webapplication?

`Secure enough` is a concept that depends on the data that your application has access to. If it's nothing sensitive, and you know that your app can't really be abused by an attacker, then it is fine to have only some basic security in place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That's what I thought as well. My current implementation is indeed the same like session cookies. But that raises the question - for me - when would a JWT be considered? Only with API calls in a SPA?

Comment: JWTs (or access tokens in general) are usually used when you have to call APIs directly from the SPA, so you don't have a backend in between which can handle sessions, or when the call is to an API in another domain (so you can't use your cookie). They are sometimes used for session management, but in my opinion, it's wrong, as JWTs were not designed to deal with sessions. Lately, it's even been recommended not to use JWTs in browsers at all as they are not safe there, and instead, use backend components that can translate cookies into access tokens.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! So JWTs are mostly used for cross-domain authentication and Session Cookies for same?-domain authentication?

Comment: I wouldn't go that far. There are many SPAs out there, that consume APIs in the same domain, but use JWTs as they might not have access to any backend which would handle sessions.